# Converting list of objects with map to array of primitives

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I keep finding pieces of something I need to do, but I'm having trouble putting it all together. To start, here is my object, put simply:

```
Object1
    Object2
        Map<String, Double>
```

What I need to do is, starting with a list of `Object1`, get a `double[]` for the values of the map given a specific key (all Objects in the list have the same N keys in the map).

Here was my starting attempt:

```
myList.stream().map(Object1::getObject2).map(Object2::getMyMap).map(m -> m.get(key).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
```

I'm not sure how to get to the primitive array from here. If this is good so far, where do I go from here? If there a better way to do this whole thing, I'm open to suggestions. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `.mapToDouble` to make a `DoubleStream`:

```
myList.stream()
    .map(Object1::getObject2)
    .map(Object2::getMyMap)
    .mapToDouble(m -> m.get(key))  // or throw if key is not in map
    .toArray();
```

Comment: Careful with `null` values.

Comment: To not throw, do this: `myList.stream().map(o -> o.getObject2().getMyMap().get(key)).filter(d -> d != null).mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray()`

Comment: Based on OP's description, throwing is probably more appropriate.  If one of the maps is missing the `key`, the data is invalid and the code should fail fast rather than return a shorter array.

Comment: Or maybe `mapToDouble(m -> m.getOrDefault(key, 0.0))`. Who knows? We are speculating here. Let's let the OP decide what's better when there's no entry for the given key.